# Tic tac toe program user input correction needed

Tags: c, codeblocks

I am building a tic tac toe game as an assignment which will put two users vs each other. I have gotten the game to run but a requirement of the game is to "ask the user to enter their move with integers in between 0 and 2, inclusive, specifying the row and column of the square to place a piece." As I have it know the user chooses a number 1-9 and enters that but based on the question i have to format it to get two numbers 1 specifying row and the other column eg 1 = 0,0    2 = 0,1  and so on. I am fairly new to programming can anyone help me implement this or point me in the right direction; also any comments or changes to the main program to improve it is welcomed.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()
{
   int winner = 0, count = 0;
     int data[9], index, letter, user, flag, i, k;

    for (i = 0; i < 9; i++)
            data[i] = ' ';

    while (count < 9) {
            flag = 0;
            printf("\n\n");
            printf("\t\t\t  %c | %c  | %c  \n", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
            printf("\t\t\t----+----+----\n");
            printf("\t\t\t  %c | %c  | %c  \n", data[3], data[4], data[5]);
            printf("\t\t\t----+----+---\n");
            printf("\t\t\t  %c | %c  | %c  \n\n", data[6], data[7], data[8]);
            if (count % 2 == 0) {
                    letter = 'X';
                    user = 1;
            } else {
                    letter = 'O';
                    user = 2;
            }
            printf("User %d enter your move (1-9):", user);
            scanf("%d", &index);
            if (index < 1 || index > 9) {
                    printf("Allowed index is 1 to 9!!\n");
                    continue;
            }
            if (data[index - 1] == 'X' || data[index - 1] == 'O') {
                    printf("Position already occupied!!\n");
                    continue;
            }
            data[index - 1] = letter;
            count++;

            for (i = 0; i < 9; i++) {
                    if (i % 3 == 0)
                            flag = 0;

                    if (data[i] == letter)
                            flag++;

                    if (flag == 3) {
                            winner = 1;
                            goto win;
                    }
            }

            flag = 0;
            for (i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
                    for (k = i; k <= i + 6; k = k + 3) {
                            if (data[k] == letter)
                                    flag++;
                    }
                    if (flag == 3) {
                            winner = 1;
                            goto win;
                    }
                    flag = 0;
            }
            if ((data[0] == letter && data[4] == letter && data[8] == letter) ||
                    (data[2] == letter && data[4] == letter && data[6] ==  letter)) {
                    winner = 1;
                    goto win;
            }
       }
  win:
        printf("\n\n");
        printf("\t\t\t  %c | %c  | %c  \n", data[0], data[1], data[2]);
        printf("\t\t\t----+----+----\n");
        printf("\t\t\t  %c | %c  | %c  \n", data[3], data[4], data[5]);
        printf("\t\t\t----+----+---\n");
        printf("\t\t\t  %c | %c  | %c  \n\n", data[6], data[7], data[8]);
        if (winner) {
                printf("User %d is the winner. Congrats!!\n", user);
       } else {
            printf("The game is a tie\n");
        }
        return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the index variable you have, you'll want an x variable and a y variable. Then, instead of `scanf("%d", &index);`, you could do `scanf("%d,%d", &x, &y);` (the player will have to enter a comma in this example.)

Then, assuming we have a variable called "board_width" which equals 3 (because I like to avoid magic numbers,) we could get the position from the user's input using `data[(y * board_width) + x]`